# Commit docker during python executing

Tags: docker

I would like to commit a docker container during executing python commands in the python shell.

My container is simply instantiated from python:3.8.

I start the container and open a shell in it:

```
docker run -it python:3.8 /bin/bash
```

In the container, I open the python shell and import a library:

```
root@a46b8fb358cc:/usr/src/app# python
Python 3.8.11 (default, Jun 29 2021, 19:54:56)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

Now, outside of the container, I commit the container:

```
docker commit [containerId] pyton_container
```

What I now would like to have, is running the container again and finding myself back with the opened python script, already having tensorflow imported. My main goal is saving the time to import tensorflow.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this programmatically through a dockerfile?

Thanks and best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Dockerfile will look like this

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN pip install tensorflow
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py .
CMD ./app.py
```

app.py will contain your code like

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

you directory structure will look like this

```
deploy/
├── app.py
└── Dockerfile
```

Inside deploy directory you will execute

```
docker build -t yourimagename:yourtag .
```

above command will build your image
whatever you are doing inside the container you have to copy it in app.py